# How to center Icons-Only Task Manager in KDE?

Tags: kde, kde-plasma-5

I want to set up a panel with two small widgets in corners and Icons-Only Task Manager in the center, and I have an issue with centering the task manager widget. This widget takes additional space on the right, and if I add two spacers on both sides, icons are not exactly centered. Here's the demonstration:

Without second spacer: [image: Without second spacer]

With second spacer: [image: With second spacer]

How could I achieve behavior I described?

Comment: Widget on the first screenshot seems like centered, but if I close one window, it shifts to wrong position.

Answer (score 4):

you can simply add two spacers, and with a right click, uncheck the box about flexible size

I hope that's what you were searching

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Right click -> enter edit mode -> add spacers. Then drag until you get things centered.